# Can't handle tinychat broadcasting option

Tags: networking, webcam

I was hanging on the website bobisnothing.com and I want to use webcam of my laptop in order to make a broadcasting. But when I click on the button "start broadcasting" I have to click "allow" to start it. But in the settings of this tinychat, I can't even touch any button! I tried to do it in a Win XP and Win 8 computer and it worked well.

It acts like it is a whole picture. I can't even close it after I open it. I have to click "allow" button but I can't.

Any idea to solve it?

[image: Can't handle the settings]

Comment: Do you have flash installed on your system? Have you tried chrome instead? Chrome over chromium simply because chrome will have flash built in already. https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?platform=linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the bug with `Firefox` on a 13.10 system.

I'd suggest to install `Google Chrome` to get access to the Adobe Flash player settings.

Comment: do you mean chromium web browser? because it did not work, too. :(

Comment: No, the Google one. You can download it [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/).

Comment: Man, thank you so much! I downloaded it and it worked well. thanks so very much again!